# Android 2.3.4 not loading FontSquirrel fonts?

Tags: android, webfonts

I've been using Pictos and FontSquirrel for fancy dancy icons and typography on our web app. Today I saw that Droid phones and Android 2.3.4 (running on VirtualBox) does not display the font face at all. For the record, Google's own web fonts DO display properly.

Is there a known work around?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Pictos';
    src: url('pictos-web.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('pictos-web.woff') format('woff'), url('pictos-web$
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Be advised that the [bulletproof](http://readableweb.com/mo-bulletproofer-font-face-css-syntax/) and [bulletproof smiley](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/#smiley) methods you're using do not work on Android phones.

Try the [Fontspring](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax) syntax.

**Example:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Pictos';
    src: url('pictos-web.eot');
    src: url('pictos-web.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('pictos-web.woff') format('woff'),
         url('pictos-web.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('pictos-web.svg#UbuntuBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If eliminating the smiley syntax doesn't work... some browsers on android are rejecting "web-only" fonts. You can run them through the fontsquirrel generator without protection and use the unprotected woff file.